# Flask Restul Basic Authentication

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have following code for flask restful basic authentication

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, prefix="/api/v1")
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

USER_DATA = {
    "admin": "SuperSecretPwd"
}


@auth.verify_password
def verify(username, password):
    if not (username and password):
        return False
    return USER_DATA.get(username) == password


class PrivateResource(Resource):
    @auth.login_required
    def get(self):
        return {"meaning_of_life": 42}


api.add_resource(PrivateResource, '/private')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But if My resource class `PrivateResource` is in separate file, how can I use @auth.login_required. I don't want to import app.py in every resource file.

Answer (score 1):

You can structure your project like this:
In `app.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api
from my_resource import PrivateResource

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, prefix="/api/v1")

# add all resources here
api.add_resource(PrivateResource, '/private')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Handle authentication in `authentication.py`

```
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth

auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

USER_DATA = {
    "admin": "SuperSecretPwd"
}

@auth.verify_password
def verify(username, password):
    if not (username and password):
        return False
    return USER_DATA.get(username) == password
```

and your resources in separate files like `my_resource.py`

```
from flask_restful import Resource
from authentication import auth

class PrivateResource(Resource):
    @auth.login_required
    def get(self):
        return {"meaning_of_life": 42}
```

Answer (score 1):

If every resource requires authentication, you can add the decorator automatically to every resource, see the decorators parameters in the third line

```
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api

application: Flask = Flask(__name__)
auth = HTTPBasicAuth()
api: Api = Api(app=application, serve_challenge_on_401=True, decorators=[auth.login_required])
PW_HASH: str = ..

@auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username: str, password: str):
    if username == 'foo' and check_password_hash(PW_HASH, password):
        return username
```

Answer (score 0):

You always need to import the auth instance from app.py, because you are creating a new instance of Auth by calling `auth = HTTPBasicAuth()`. And you are registering your validation method on that specific instance, see `@auth.verify_password`. So only this instance is able to handle your authentication. So you need to import it every time you want to use it. But you don't need to import the whole module. Its enough to import only that instance: `from app.py import auth`